# Java Mac OS X - Programmatically compute screen height without the Dock height

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, javafx, screen-size

I need this to make the application open in full height-width (without full screen), but the size should be exact without the dock (setting the size of a javafx.scene.Scene so big creates some problems in the title double clicking behaviour).

I tried with this code:

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
return new Dimension(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

It works but it considers the Dock as part of the screen.
Is there a way to programmatically compute screen height without the Dock height or at least to compute the size of the dock?

---

I also tested this solution but the strange double click behaviour continues to persist :

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("title");
        Rectangle bounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight(), Color.WHITE);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For AWT and Swing, you can get the appropriate size for a window by using the class [`GraphicsEnvironment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html). Although a machine may have many graphics environments, you get access to the screen by calling the static method `getLocalGraphicsEnvironment`.

Then you can use the `getMaximumWindowBounds()`. This gives you the boundaries, including top, left, bottom and right, to which you should limit your window. Note that it's not just a matter of width and height: The Dock can be located on the left or on the right. And it also takes the menu bar into account, which `Toolkit.getScreenSize` doesn't. So take care to also set the origin of your window properly.

```
java.awt.Rectangle bounds = GraphicsEnvironment
                            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                            .getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

---

For JavaFX, you can use the [`Screen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class. In this case, you use:

```
javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
```

The returned `Rectangle2D` contains `maxX` and `maxY`, which are the width and height of the complete screen, and `width` and `height` that are what you need - the values with the dock and menu bar eliminated.

Comment: I have a fixed dock at the bottom of my screen, the height-width print for the toolkit code gives me `900.0 - 1440.0`and for the GraphicsEnvironment code (yours) `826.0 - 1440.0`. See above, I added the code in which I would like to get the correct size. Maybe I missed something, however it continues to give me the double click problem. I know that maybe I'm going a little bit out from my initial question, but what could be the problem? I think it's the size... Have you an idea? Thanks

Comment: @madx I can't say. You should edit your question to explain exactly what the double click issue is, and when you see it happening.